# how to create a SETUP.EXE wrapper for an MSI file using NSIS

Tags: windows-installer, installation, nsis

I want to wrap a existing msi installer file into NSIS installer executable. Because there is not any option to change the icon of the msi file. I just want to customize the icon of the output setup.exe. Along with this I would also want to make sure that NSIS does not add any extra user interface into my installer. Have anybody an idea to do this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, just for the icon? kinda overkill don't you think?

Comment: Really, these are not tags!!!

Comment: hahaha, that was the best tagging I have seen on SO. The tag itself conveys the question directly !! :P

Answer (score 4):

The NSIS attributes you want are: Icon and SilentInstall

You execute a .msi by running msiexec.exe with ExecWait (Search NSIS forum and wiki for examples)

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for this purpose, it includes a module specifically for creating self-extracting installer files with no additional UI.

Answer (score 1):

Just to change icon use an old utility called [resource hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to give this a try:
[Program Icon Changer](http://www.exeicon.com/program-icon-changer/)
[Change exe icon - Icon Changer](http://www.shelllabs.com/change_exe_icon.htm)

There are probably free ones out there too, though I have yet to find one :P

Comment: You can't change the nsis icon without breaking the crc check. As far as free resource editors, there are several, google Resource Hacker for example